# Node.js MySQL JWT Multiple Queries

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am building a Node.js API utilizing MySQL.

> How can I do bulk inserts in MySqL WHILE being able to utilize
>   results from a middleware from my authentication?

This is what I am referring to with this question. I have a route:

```
api.post('/', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    db.query(`INSERT INTO test_workouts (assigned_date, completed, name, length, userid)
              VALUES ?;`, [req.body], (error, workouts) => {
            if (error) {
                res.send({ error });
            };
            res.send({ Message: 'Successfully Added Workout' })
    });
});
```

You can see that I have a middleware called `authenticate`. This is to check the validation of the JWT that was sent in the Authorization header. I can decode this JWT and use the userId value in it in this INSERT query.

I do get a parameter from the authenticate query of `req.user` which has the decoded JWT token. However, I am not sure how to add this into the original values array I am receiving from the API POST.

The data I am posting in the API looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO test_workouts (assigned_date, completed, name, length, userid)
VALUES ('2018-04-03 12:00:00PM', '0', 'Lower Body', '90', '3'), ('2018-04-04 12:00:00PM', '0', 'Upper Body', '90', '3'), ('2018-04-05 12:00:00PM', '0', 'Full Body', '90', '3');
```

However, what I would like to do is to replace the final value in each of these (the '3') with the userId that is coming from the JWT.

Comment: You didn't describe your `authenticate` middleware. Many middlewares put extra fields onto the `req` object. So, you might look for something like `req.auth.jwt.userid` in your route code. But this is a pure guess.

Comment: And please, one question only per StackOverflow question. You have two here.